# Visual Basic の入力ファイル処理について

Tags: vb.net

vs2019でvbコードを作成していましたが、自己解決出来なかったため投稿しました。

「load.csv」ファイルで1行ずつ読込み、ILが1か2によってFPini、Piniに数値を格納させるものです。
3行分のデーターのため、「NL=3」としています。

「load.txt」に出力させると、下記のとおり1行目のデーターが3回繰り返されて同じ値が格納されてしまいます。
3行毎のデーターとして違う値が格納されません。

どのようにすれば1行毎に更新されて正しく数値を格納できるでしょうか。
コードを示しますのでアドバイス頂けますと有難く存じます。

①入力ファイル「load.csv」

```
1   6   0   80  80  0   80  -80
1   7   0   80  80  0   80  -80
2   2   100 0   0
```

②出力ファイル「load.txt」

```
 1,  6,  0,  80,  80,  0,  80, -80
 1,  6,  0,  80,  80,  0,  80, -80
 1,  6,  0,  80,  80,  0,  80, -80
```

③コード

```
Public Pini(600) As Double, FPini(7, 300) As Double
Public PDATA(3), FPDATA(7)


        Dim Reader4 As New IO.StreamReader("./load.csv", System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("Shift-JIS"))
        Dim dat4() As String                
        Dim Line4 As String = Reader4.ReadLine 
        Dim LineW4 As New IO.StreamWriter("./load.txt", False, System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("shift_jis"))

        Dim aa4$

        dat4 = Line4.Split(",")            
 
        For IM = 1 To NL

            IL = dat4(0)    

        If IL = 1 Then
    
            IMM = dat4(1)                  
            FPDATA(1) = dat4(2)                  
            FPDATA(2) = dat4(3)                   
            FPDATA(3) = dat4(4)                  
            FPDATA(4) = dat4(5)               
            FPDATA(5) = dat4(6)                   
            FPDATA(6) = dat4(7)                 

            For I = 1 To 7
                FPini(I, IMM) = FPDATA(I)
            Next

            aa4$ = Str$(IL) + ", " + Str$(IMM)+ ", " + Str$(FPDATA(1))+ ", " + Str$(FPDATA(2)) + ", " + Str$(FPDATA(3))+ ", " + Str$(FPDATA(4))+ ", " + Str$(FPDATA(5))+ ", " + Str$(FPDATA(6))

                LineW4.WriteLine(aa4$)

             ElseIf IL = 2 Then

            INN = dat4(1)                    
            PDATA(1) = dat4(2)                  
            PDATA(2) = dat4(3)                   
            PDATA(3) = dat4(4)                   

            For I = 1 To 3
                II = (INN - 1) * 3 + I
                Pini(II) = PDATA(I)
            Next

                aa4$ = aa4$ + Str$(IL) + ", " + Str$(INN) + ", " + Str$(PDATA(1)) + ", " + Str$(PDATA(2)) + ", " + Str$(PDATA(3))

                LineW4.WriteLine(aa4$)

            End If

             Line4 = Reader4.ReadLine       

        Next IM
 
        Reader4.Close()
        LineW4.Close()
```

Comment: 入力ファイルにカンマがありませんよ。入力ファイルと出力ファイルを間違ってませんか？

Answer (score 1):

`dat4`の設定・更新がループの始まる前に1回行われているだけで、ループが廻っても更新されないことが原因ですね。

それから`dat4`の更新に使う`Line4`へのcsvファイルからの読み込みが変数の宣言時とループの末尾の2か所に分かれていて、かつ`dat4`の更新からも離れていることが問題を判り難くしているのでは？

こんな風に変更すると良いでしょう。

1. `Line4`の宣言は宣言だけしてファイルからの読み込みは行わない
   `Dim Line4 As String = Reader4.ReadLine` は `Dim Line4 As String` に変更する
2. csvファイルからの1行読み込みである`For IM = 1 To NL`ループの末尾の`Line4 = Reader4.ReadLine`はループの先頭に移動する
3. `dat4`の設定・更新である`dat4 = Line4.Split(",")`はループの外にあったものを上記`Line4 = Reader4.ReadLine`の次の行へ移動する

つまり前後は省略しますが、ループの先頭部分はこんな風になるでしょう。

```
        For IM = 1 To NL

            Line4 = Reader4.ReadLine
            dat4 = Line4.Split(",")
            IL = dat4(0)

            If IL = 1 Then
```

Comment: 無事に成功しました。dat4 = Line4.Split(",")がループの外にあったのが大きな原因でした。NL数を増やしてテストしましたが無事反映されました。有難うございました。